# Kill a process when user presses “logoff”, “shutdown” or “restart”

Tags: windows-7, notepad, logoff

I often use notepad.exe for temporary messages. I never use it for something I need to save: I have normal text editors and MS OneNote for that.

When I shut down, multiple instances of Notepad is asking to save.
What's worse, because of the Windows bug, when I press “no don’t save”, the notepad application stays alive, so I have to close it manually, and once again press “no don’t save”.

I’ve been fighting this problem for years. About 2 years ago, I’ve asked one of the software developers in my team to hack notepad.exe so it doesn’t asks for saving. Unfortunately, I had to reinstall my Windows recently, and I no longer work with that brilliant guy.

Then I’ve tried to use group policy with `taskkill /f /im notepad.exe` logoff script, only to find out the logoff script is executed after all application are terminated.

I don’t want to install third-party notepad replacements.

I don’t want to disable shutdown prevention at all by tweaking registry. I want the apps like word and excel to be able to prevent shutdown. The problem is only with notepad.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't say I've run into the "Windows bug" to which you refer.

Comment: Amusingly I use that specifically to keep windows from shutting down when I don't want it to.

Comment: @RandolphWest, steps to reproduce: 1. Open notepad, type something. 2. Press Windows, Logoff. Wait for the screen to dim, saying "1 program still need to close". 3. Press Cancel on that screen. 4. You'll see a notepad asking "do you want to save changes?" with buttons "Save, Don't Save, Cancel". Press "Don't Save". Expected result: notepad should quit without saving. Actual result: notepad stays running. After that "1 program still need to close" screen, "Don't Save" and "Cancel" buttons are equivalent - WTF?

Comment: It turns out I've been using Notepad2 for so many years, I've not run into this on Vista or Windows 7 :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about [removing Shutdown and Restart from the Start Menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7553/remove-shutdown-and-restart-buttons-in-windows-7/), [disabling the Switch User, Log off and Lock options](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprovirt/thread/2bb6ae34-c764-469f-8eb5-06f20a17ffd4) as well, then creating your own batch files for these actions that will first taskkill notepad and then perform the action (shutdown etc.) required using [shutdown.exe or rundll32](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/how-do-i-create-shutdown-shortcuts-in-microsoft-windows-7/2048)? You can pin the batch file shortcuts to the taskbar or Start Menu, and even assign keyboard shortcuts to them.